# Edit/modify array of objects in React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

***updated code!***

So I am trying to fetch a json file with an array of objects, load it to an editing form and when clicking the submit button, save and update the array.

Here is a part of my code:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
const API = "https://www.mocky.io/v2/581335f71000004204abaf83";

class EditContact extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        contacts: [],
    }
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
  fetch(API)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => this.setState({ contacts: data.contacts }))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
}  

onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.editContact(this.state);
    //am I thinking right?
}

editContact(EditWithThisValue)
{
    const  { contacts } = this.state;
    const updated = {
    ...contacts, 
    //what goes here
    }
}

handleInputChange = (event) => {
const target = event.target;
const value = target.value;
const name = target.name;
this.setState({
    [name]: value
});
console.log(this.state);


 }

render() {
const { search, sortIt, sortBy, direction, deleteContact, editContact} = this.props;
const {name, contacts} = this.state;
const contactDetail = (contacts) =>
    <ul className="gradient_text" key={contacts.name}>
    <li>Name: <input name="name" id="name" onChange={this.handleInputChange} defaultValue={contacts.name}/></li>
    <li>Phone: <input name="phone_number" id="phone_number" onChange={this.handleInputChange} defaultValue={contacts.phone_number}/></li>
    <li>Address: <input name="address" id="address" onChange={this.handleInputChange} defaultValue={contacts.address}/></li>
    <button onClick={() => this.onSubmit(contacts)}>Save</button>
    <hr />
    </ul>

if (direction === 'notsorted') {
let filteredAndSortedData = contacts.filter(
contacts => {
return contacts.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
contacts.address.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
contacts.phone_number.includes(search);
})
    return (
        <div>
        {filteredAndSortedData.map(contactDetail)}    
        </div>
        );

}
else if........
}
}


export default EditContact;
```

I am stuck at handleInputChange, how am I supposed to pass the state to the submit. What I was trying to achieve to first fill the form fields from the state and then pass the updated state ...but I am completely lost. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I didn't understand what's your problem. You're able to access this.state inside your onSubmit function, why do you think you can't?.

Comment: I am getting in this.state the original contacts array and if there is any change in the textfield I have it in this.state too. When clicking on Save should I pass a parameter to onSubmit() or onSubmit(contacts) and in that 
onSubmit(event) {
event.preventDefault();
this.editContact(this.state);
}

Comment: I have updated the code. Hopefully it is much cleared now where I am stuck. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onClick={() => this.onSubmit(contacts)}>Save</button>
```

So you will be able to get current contract data in `onSubmit` function.